# How to delete all files except some specific file (for many folders in a directory)? via bash script

Tags: linux, windows, bash, bash-scripting

So I have a Master folder that contains about 800 sub-folders (eg. 1,2,3...) which contains many files but I want to delete everything else except the file that ends with *tsv.
Is there a way to do this via a bash script?

### Master Folder

Folder #1

- sample.txt
- sample2.txt
- test.tsv
- sample.tsv

Folder #2

- sample.txt
- sample2.txt
- test.tsv
- sample.tsv

and so on..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, please check if the methods in the following link was helpful to you: [3 Ways to Delete All Files in a Directory Except One or Few Files with Extensions](https://www.tecmint.com/delete-all-files-in-directory-except-one-few-file-extensions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Linux:

You can use this command:

```
find . ! -name '*.tsv' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

This command will delete all files except the files that match the pattern after `-name` flag (`'*.tsv'` in this case). All folders will be preserved.

(Answer adapted from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153863).)

### Windows:

I made it work with this command:

```
for /R %f in (*.*) do @echo %f | findstr /v ".tsv" | for /f %f in ('more') do @del "%f"
```

There are probably more elegant ways, but it does the job.

Comment: I did cd Master_folder (eg. test here) and ran the command line you provided but getting this error:  (base) C:\Users\kimc26\Desktop\NER\failure\test>find . ! -name '*.tsv' -type f -exec rm -f {} +

File not found - '*.tsv'

Comment: @JJ_K You did not put `*` in `-name` parameter. `*.tsv` Ofcourse you did not find any file named. ".tsv". * It is a wild card character. It basically means any string value can be on the side of the `*` character.

Comment: i ran the same command with * in -name parameter. *.tsv but it says File not found - *.tsv

Comment: @JJ_K Apologies, I just realised you are on a Windows machine. I updated the post with a command that works in Command Prompt.

Comment: @JJ_K to reply to your (now deleted) question about performance: I tested the command with 30 folders, each containing 10 files of size ~100MB (two of which were .tsv); the command finished in about 9 seconds. (i wanted to test with more folders but it took too long to generate them hah)

Comment: The new command worked! 

Also I have another question, in these folders (#1, #2, #3..) I also have a folder named 'eval' and I want to get rid of these as well.

With your command, I was able to get rid of all tsv files, now I want to get rid of this folder name called 'eval', can you help?

Thank you!